# How to get placement coordinates of an absolutely positioned element relative to another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to find this on github so here we go:

Suppose I have DOM element `parent` which contains `position: relative` and another element `child` which contains `position: absolute` and is a child of parent, how can I go about getting coordinates [top, left] for my child element [relative to parent] given some placement string? (i.e. "top left", "top middle", "bottom right", and so forth... ?)

Ideally, something like this:

```
var coordinates = getRelativeCoordinates({
  el:           child        // Child element which contains "position: absolute"
  relativeToEl: parent       // Parent container which contains "position: relative"
  placement:    "top left"   // "top left" || "top middle" || "top right" || "right top" || etc...
});

console.log(coordinates);
>> {top: "-100px", left: "0px"}
```

Comment: "how can I go about getting coordinates [top, left] for my child element..." Coordinates from which point of reference?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. I need coordinates of the child element relative to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

"When position is set to absolute, the element is removed from the normal document flow—that is, it no longer takes up space and may overlap with other elements. Also, its top and left properties can be used to absolutely position it relative to the top-left corner of the nearest enclosing element whose position property isn’t static, or relative to the document if no such enclosing element exists." - http://eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html

Then all you need to do is compute:
If you know the `.width` and `.height` properties, you can compute the different places by adding to the top left the amount of width or height.

ex. (top middle) = (`(parseInt(child.style.left) + parseInt(child.style.width)/2)` , `parseInt(child.style.top)`) (x, y)

note `parseInt` is used to get a number with out the "px".

you will need to write out each possible location as a computation like this. You could store them as an array [left, top] or in a object {left: , top: }.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/eU3pN/116/)

The `HTMLElement.offsetLeft` read-only method returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left within the `HTMLElement.offsetParent` node (i.e. the nearest parent with position absolute or relative).

javascript

```
var obj = document.getElementById("child");
var left = obj.offsetLeft;
var top = obj.offsetTop;

alert("left : " + left + ", right : " + top);

// offsetTop, offsetWidth, and offsetHeight are other such method.
```

html

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
    font-size:0;
}
.a {
    height: 100px;
    background: #bbb;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.b {
    height: 300px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #d3145a;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your request, you need a function like this:

```
function getCoordinates(element, y, x) {
    // possible values: top, middle, bottom
    y = y || 'top';
    // possible values: left, middle, right
    x = x || 'left';

    var top = element.offsetTop,
        left = element.offsetLeft;

    switch (y) {
        case 'middle':
            top += element.offsetHeight / 2;
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            top += element.offsetHeight;
    }

    switch (x) {
        case 'middle':
            left += element.offsetWidth / 2;
            break;
        case 'right':
            left += element.offsetWidth;
    }
    return {top: top, left: left}
}
```

When you absolute position an element, it is absolute to the nearest relative (or document if none are relative positioned). So if you want to get the position relative to it's "relative" parent, you just need its "natural" offset. In my code I also add the full or the half of the height or width, depending on the y and x variables passed as arguments, like this:

```
console.log(getCoordinates(document.getElementById('inner')));
console.log(getCoordinates(document.getElementById('inner'), 'middle', 'middle'));
console.log(getCoordinates(document.getElementById('inner', 'bottom', 'right')));
```

Live preview:

http://jsfiddle.net/884ud4yj/